# Name for sum of diagonals for Hilbert Schmidt normalized matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, reference-request, matrix-norms

Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. Then the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of $A$ is given by
$$
\vert \vert A \vert \vert_{HS}^2= \sum_{i,j=1}^n \vert{A_{i,j} \vert}^2. 
$$
Now, if I insist that $ \vert \vert A \vert \vert_{HS}^2 =1$ then the number $c(A)$ defined by
$$ c(A)= \sum_{i=1}^n \vert{A_{i,i} \vert}^2 $$
is in $\lbrack 0,1 \rbrack$.

Does $c(A)$ have a name? Does it have any nice properties?

Comment: In the case of a quantum state which is Hilbert-Schmidt normalized the number $c$ is describing how classical the state is. This is discussed here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.09879

Answer (score 1):

Use an unconstrained matrix $(U)$, the identity matrix $(I)$, the Hadamard product $(U\odot V)$ and the matrix inner product $\big(U:V={\rm tr}(U^TV)\big)$ to construct the constrained matrix $(A)$ and the scalar $(c)$
$$\eqalign{
A &= \frac{U}{\|U\|} \qquad\implies\quad A:A = \frac{U:U}{U:U} = 1 \\
c &= (I\odot A):(I\odot A) 
   = \frac{(I\odot U):(I\odot U)}{U:U} \\
}$$
Since denominator selects all components of $U\,$ while the numerator selects only the diagonal components, the scalar function $c$ becomes a measure of the *diagonal-ness* of a given matrix.

In particular, note that

If $\,U\,$ is a diagonal matrix, then $c=1$

If $\,U\,$ has zeros along its diagonal, then $c=0$

Otherwise, $\;0\lt c\lt 1$